# Why am I unable to interact with my Button? Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the code below. I added a button and want something to happen when I press it, but it doesn't seem to work. In this case I want the system to print out "hi" and "hey". I can't seem to figure out the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var containerView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var buttonOne: UIButton!

        buttonOne = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        buttonOne.setTitle("Level 1", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        buttonOne.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 100)
        buttonOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        buttonOne.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)
        buttonOne.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        buttonOne.addTarget(self, action: Selector("clicked:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
        self.scrollView.delegate = self
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 1000)

        containerView = UIView()

        scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        containerView.addSubview(buttonOne)
    }

    func clicked(sender: AnyObject){
        NSLog("Hey")
        print("hi")
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        scrollView.frame = view.bounds
        containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you see the button?

Comment: yes. Its a blue button that appears in the top left corner of my screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put the button in a scrollview. Here, the scrollview is a superview of the button and the width of the scrollview and its content size width must be greater than or equal to the button width to take action.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the containerView's width to 0 by setting its bounds size to the contentSize of the scrollview

`self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 1000)`


then

```
 containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width,
                                        scrollView.contentSize.height)
```